# Own OSM map tile server seems not to render or is very slow

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik, server, openmaptiles

I have a problem with my own tile server. I tested it with https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany/bayern-latest.osm.pbf and everything works fine. At the beginning it took about 200 seconds to render the first tile but then it worked quite good. After this I load up another set https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany/saarland-latest.osm.pbf with –create and it worked still. Then I wanted to try the same with a bigger set (Germany, Switzerland, Austria) http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/dach-latest.osm.pbf. It took about 12 hours to process the osm2pgsql. Now I started the tile server again and it seems not to work. Other possibility is that it is very slow. Here is the grep rendered:

```
Mar 24 10:36:47 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/unifont/unifont_csur.ttf
Mar 24 10:36:47 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/unifont/unifont.ttf
Mar 24 10:36:47 h2929534 renderd[8445]: Loading parameterization function for
Mar 24 10:36:47 h2929534 renderd[8445]: Starting stats thread
Mar 24 10:36:47 h2929534 renderd[8445]: Loading parameterization function for
Mar 24 10:36:47 h2929534 renderd[8445]: message repeated 5 times: [ Loading parameterization function for]
Mar 24 10:36:54 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 8, number 1
Mar 24 10:36:54 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
Mar 24 10:36:54 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Got command RenderPrio fd(8) xml(ajt), z(19), x(247506), y(167636), mime(image/png), options()
Mar 24 10:36:56 h2929534 renderd[8445]: Using web mercator projection settings
Mar 24 10:36:56 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: START TILE ajt 19 247504-247511 167632-167639, new metatile
Mar 24 10:36:56 h2929534 renderd[8445]: Rendering projected coordinates 19 247504 167632 -> -1119038.094096|7223604.921066 -1118426.597869|7224216.417292 to a 8 x 8 tile
Mar 24 10:36:57 h2929534 renderd[8445]: Using web mercator projection settings
Mar 24 10:36:57 h2929534 renderd[8445]: message repeated 5 times: [ Using web mercator projection settings]
Mar 24 10:37:24 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Connection 0, fd 8 closed, now 0 left
Mar 24 10:37:45 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 7, number 1
Mar 24 10:37:45 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
Mar 24 10:37:45 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Got command RenderPrio fd(7) xml(ajt), z(19), x(247506), y(167636), mime(image/png), options()
Mar 24 10:38:15 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Connection 0, fd 7 closed, now 0 left
Mar 24 10:39:21 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 7, number 1
Mar 24 10:39:21 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
Mar 24 10:39:21 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Got command RenderPrio fd(7) xml(ajt), z(19), x(247506), y(167636), mime(image/png), options()
Mar 24 10:39:51 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Connection 0, fd 7 closed, now 0 left
Mar 24 10:43:44 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 7, number 1
Mar 24 10:43:44 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
Mar 24 10:43:44 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Got command RenderPrio fd(7) xml(ajt), z(19), x(247506), y(167636), mime(image/png), options()
Mar 24 10:44:14 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Connection 0, fd 7 closed, now 0 left
Mar 24 10:59:42 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 7, number 1
Mar 24 10:59:42 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
Mar 24 10:59:42 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Got command RenderPrio fd(7) xml(ajt), z(19), x(247506), y(167636), mime(image/png), options()
Mar 24 11:00:12 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Connection 0, fd 7 closed, now 0 left
Mar 24 11:00:56 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 7, number 1
Mar 24 11:00:57 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
Mar 24 11:00:57 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Got command RenderPrio fd(7) xml(ajt), z(19), x(247506), y(167636), mime(image/png), options()
Mar 24 11:01:26 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Connection 0, fd 7 closed, now 0 left
Mar 24 11:11:53 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 7, number 1
Mar 24 11:11:53 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
Mar 24 11:11:53 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Got command RenderPrio fd(7) xml(ajt), z(19), x(247506), y(167636), mime(image/png), options()
Mar 24 11:12:23 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Connection 0, fd 7 closed, now 0 left
Mar 24 11:13:48 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 7, number 1
Mar 24 11:13:48 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
Mar 24 11:13:48 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Got command RenderPrio fd(7) xml(ajt), z(19), x(247506), y(167636), mime(image/png), options()
Mar 24 11:14:18 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Connection 0, fd 7 closed, now 0 left
Mar 24 11:16:09 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 7, number 1
Mar 24 11:16:09 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
Mar 24 11:16:09 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Got command RenderPrio fd(7) xml(ajt), z(19), x(247506), y(167636), mime(image/png), options()
Mar 24 11:16:39 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Connection 0, fd 7 closed, now 0 left
Mar 24 11:21:53 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 7, number 1
Mar 24 11:21:53 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
Mar 24 11:21:53 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Got command RenderPrio fd(7) xml(ajt), z(19), x(247506), y(167636), mime(image/png), options()
Mar 24 11:22:23 h2929534 renderd[8445]: DEBUG: Connection 0, fd 7 closed, now 0 left
```

I tried to render the /hot/19/247506/167636.png

System:
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on V-Server
32 GB ram
800 GB SSD 8 core cpu

Comment: 12H sounds quite long, have you tweaked Postgres config for this loading task? for Postgis tasks? Also have you created (partial) indexes on the fields used to style the data?

Comment: Yes i changed the postgres config. In /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf i changed following value:
shared_buffers = 6GB
work_mem = 500MB
maintenance_wokr_mem = 4GB
effecitve_cache_size = 10GB

What do you mean with the partial indexes on the fields?

Strange thing is that everything works good with smaller pbfs (up to 600 MB). But for 4.3GB pbf it doesn't.

Comment: Maybe also something else which is interesting. Only 6 of the 32GB memory are used right now by trying to render and about 2% of the cpu are used.

Comment: Partial indexes (in openstreetmap-carto style, OSM default style) https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/blob/master/indexes.sql

Comment: Ah, yes i did. So i followed this tutorial: https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-18-04-lts/

Comment: When speed is greatly affected by size, I would put my effort on identifying missing/inadequate indexes (may on some specific hstore keys?) You can look at the slow query and run an `explain buffer analyze` on it to see the bottleneck and to find one or more solutions (ex: if a specific hstore key is needs to be indexed, try to find all keys that should be indexed else the next query will be just as slow)

Comment: On a side note, for a new project, you may want to consider using a newer version of PG and PostGIS, they are more efficient